# RP3 to Arduino - Why am I receiving unwanted bytes with pySerial?

Tags: pi-3, python, serial

I'm new to RP3, but fairly comfortable with Arduino. Maybe this is an easy one.

I am trying to use pySerial to send a single byte from a Raspberry Pi 3 to an Arduino Mega 2560, like so:

```
#RP3 python code
import serial  
s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)  
s.write(b'\x50')  


//Arduino code
byte data;
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200); 
}

void loop() {  
        if (Serial.available() > 0) {  
                data = Serial.read();  
        }  
        Serial.println(data);  
}
```

When I run the python script and enter, say, '\x50' to the Arduino, the Arduino serial monitor will show something like (80 being 0x50 in decimal):

80
121

or

80
106

The second byte is usually 106 or 121, but I've seen other values.

My pySerial and python are up-to-date. I'm using the simple Thonny python editor that comes with RP3 (just pressing the Run Script button to send the data) and the latest release of the Arduino IDE for RP.

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: You seem to be opening the port, sending one character, and then closing the port.  Perhaps a spurious character on port close?  What happens if you leave the port open and loop sending a character every second?

Comment: What happens if you try to declare your data variable as an integer? Does it throw an error?

Comment: I think it's more to do with encoding and decoding rather than the serial port itself. Also if you are using Python 2, your b prefix will be ignored.

Comment: LecauseAndThePi-- No error is thrown when I switch data from byte to int. I appear to get the same result.

Comment: LecauseAndThePi-- python --version says I'm using 2.7.13, but if I remove the b, I get an error: _unicode strings are not supported please encode to bytes: 'a'_

Comment: @joan-- When I send a value every second, I see the last byte of whatever byte array I send once per loop, but garbage in between... example: python command is: s.write([0xAA, 0xBB])  The Arduino serial monitor shows (in hex):  BB  106A  106A  106A  106A  106A  106A  106A  106A  106A BB  ...repeats....  The Arduino is checking for new serial data every 250 ms, while the RP3 is sending new serial data every second. I never see the first 0xAA byte.